# combobox not getting bound

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I am trying to bind the combobox through dataset column.

I have following dataset:

[image]

I want to bind combobox through LocationName column.

I am using following code for it:

```
cmbLocation.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", dsLocations, "LocationName"))
```

But its throwing me following error:

> Cannot bind to the property or column LocationName on the DataSource.
>   Parameter name: dataMember

Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct parameter name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for binding `ComboBox` to data source:

```
cmbLocation.DisplayMember = "LocationName";
cmbLocation.ValueMember = "LocationName";
cmbLocation.DataSource = dsLocations;
```

it is easier and IMO more readable.

Comment: what if bydefault i want to get selected first value of combo?

Comment: to get value you have to do: `var row = cmbLocation.SelectedItem as DataRow;`

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
cmbLocation.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", dsLocations, "LocationName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

If this doesnt work, replace "EditValue" with "SelectedText"

Comment: Cannot bind to the property or column LocationName on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember

Comment: You sure you assigning your datasource 'dsLocations' correctly ?

Comment: The error you getting seems otherwise. Could we maybe see your code where you give the binding source 'dsLocations' its value?